# MySQL Update Running Max

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, max

I'm trying to create a query that updates a running max column based on the running max of another column, such as score in this case.
table before query

```
time-----score---------current max
1-----------5--------------null
2-----------6--------------null
3-----------3--------------null
4-----------4--------------null
5-----------5--------------null
6-----------7--------------null
7-----------8--------------null
```

table after query

```
time-----score---------current max
1-----------5--------------5
2-----------6--------------6
3-----------3--------------6
4-----------4--------------6
5-----------5--------------6
6-----------7--------------7
7-----------8--------------8
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
select @max := case when score > @max 
                    then score
                    else @max 
               end as curr_max,
       time,
       score
from your_table, (select @max := 0) m
```

Comment: That worked to populate a new table with the current max.   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableA A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.time, (@temp:=IF(score > @temp, score, @temp)) currentMax
            FROM tableA A, (SELECT @temp:=0) B
           ) B ON A.time = B.time
SET A.currentMax = B.currentMax
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That worked perfectly to update my existing table with a running current maximum value.  Thanks again, and much appreciated!

Comment: @user3153606 You're most welcome... If you got desired output and an active member of stackoverflow try to accept and upvote the answer. How to use stackoverflow take a tour of that on this link stackoverflow.com/tour. It will describe how to accept and upvote the answer.