# Syntax for MAX() with a specific range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, max

I have this table

| ID | Date | Time | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 10:00 | 3.15 | 1.45 | 0.77 |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 11:00 | 0.00 | -0.95 | -0.89 |
| 3 | 1/2/2021 | 05:00 | -0.44 | 1.15 | -0.73 |
| 4 | 1/2/2021 | 06:00 | 0.85 | -1.00 | 0.00 |
| 5 | 1/3/2021 | 14:00 | -1.07 | 0.00 | 2.09 |
| 6 | 1/3/2021 | 15:00 | 2.05 | 1.25 | 0.00 |

I'm trying to create a new table in which I keep the columns ID, Date and Time and for each cell from 1, 2, 3 columns to use the following formula:

Current cell value minus maximum value from the range formed by the first value in the same column and the current value from the same column. So, the desired table looks like this:

| ID | Date | Time | 1.1 | 2.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 10:00 | 3.15-Max(3.15) | 1.45-Max(1.45) |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 11:00 | 0.00-Max(3.15,0.00) | -0.95-Max(1.45,-0.95) |
| 3 | 1/2/2021 | 05:00 | -0.44-Max(3.15,0.00,-0.44) | 1.15-Max(1.45,-0.95,1.15) |
| 4 | 1/2/2021 | 06:00 | 0.85-Max(3.15,0.00,-0.44,0.85) | -1.00-Max(1.45,-0.95,1.15,-1.00) |
| 5 | 1/3/2021 | 14:00 | -1.07-Max(3.15,0.00,-0.44,0.85,-1.07) | 0.00-Max(1.45,-0.95,1.15,-1.00,0.00) |
| 6 | 1/3/2021 | 15:00 | 2.05-Max(3.15,0.00,-0.44,0.85,-1.07,2.05) | 1.25-Max(1.45,-0.95,1.15,-1.00,0.00,1.25) |

I didn't write the 3rd column from the desired table because of the lack of space, but it's the same format for the 3rd column, too.

My problem is that I can't find the proper syntax for the formula mentioned earlier. I searched for it in all the ways that I could think about, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Can anyone help me, please?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

P.S. I am new to stackoverflow.com and MySQL, so, please, be kind.

Comment: You mean a running maximum with all the rows leading up to it?

Comment: In MySQL 8.x I think you can do this with window functions.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "a running maximum with all the rows leading up to it" :(

Comment: Just like a running total is the sum of all the rows up to the current one, a running maximum is the maximum of all the rows up to the current one.

Comment: Thank you for patience and clarification. A running maximum is what I need, but I can't find the right syntax. Thank you again!

Comment: See the linked question, it shows how to do it using a user variable.

Comment: It might sound dumb, but... where can I find the linked question?

Comment: In the right sidebar, under the heading **Linked**

Comment: Thank you! I found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883115/mysql-update-running-max?noredirect=1&lq=1 The problem is that I don't know how to create the syntax for my situation. :( I worked with Excel a lot, and now I was forced to move to MySQL and everything is so different. Can you help me, please?

Comment: You're right.  It's just a lot to learn. It's even harder when you don't know what to learn first. The differences between Excel and MySQL are huge. Anyway, I got your point, and I'll try to do so. Thank you very much for your time. Have a great time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MAX` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, Date, Time, `1`, `2`, `3`,
       `1` - MAX(`1`) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS `1.1`,
       `2` - MAX(`2`) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS `2.1`,
       `2` - MAX(`3`) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS `3.1`
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL which do not support analytic functions, we can use a correlated subquery here:

```sql
SELECT ID, Date, Time, `1`, `2`, `3`,
       `1` - (SELECT SUM(t2.`1`) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t1.ID) AS `1.1`,
       `2` - (SELECT SUM(t2.`2`) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t1.ID) AS `2.1`,
       `3` - (SELECT SUM(t2.`3`) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t1.ID) AS `3.1`
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer. I get a lot of errors when I do this:

Static analysis:

26 errors were found during the analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "` 1.1` "at position 83)
An alias was expected. (near "" at position 82)
Unexpected token. (near "` 1.1` "at position 83)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 88)
Unexpected token. (near "` 2` "at position 98)
Unexpected token. (near "-" at position 102)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "MAX" at position 104)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 107)

Comment: Unexpected token. (near "` 2` "at position 108)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 111)
Unexpected token. (near "OVER" at position 113)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 118)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 130)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "AS" at position 132)
Unexpected token. (near "` 2.1` "at position 135)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 140)
Unexpected token. (near "` 2` "at position 150)
Unexpected token. (near "-" at position 154)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "MAX" at position 156)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 159)

Comment: Unexpected token. (near "` 3` "at position 160)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 163)
Unexpected token. (near "OVER" at position 165)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 170)
This type of clause has been analyzed previously. (near "ORDER BY" at position 171)
Unrecognized type of activity. (near "ORDER BY" at position 171)

Comment: @MihaiOW What version of MySQL are you using? You need MySQL 8.x to get window functions.

Comment: Those don't look like MySQL error messages.

Comment: I'm new to MySQL. I'm using it via phpMyAdmin. I think it's MySQL 5.7

Comment: @MihaiOW I have added an option to my answer which should work on earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you so much. The updated version seems to make a SUM instead of a subtraction. Is there a way in which I can make it to do a subtraction? Thank you again.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am sorry to bother you again, I tried all day to figure it by myself, but I couldn't solve it. The updated answer does the right thing only in the first cell, after that it does something else.  I couldn't figure what. I even replaced 1, 2, 3 columns with One, Two and Three and 1.1, 2.1 and 3.1 with New_One, New_Two and New_Three. Can you help me, please?

Comment: This is the updated answer:

SELECT ID, Date, Time, One, Two, Three,
       One - (SELECT SUM(t2.One) FROM TR t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t1.ID) AS One.One,
       Two - (SELECT SUM(t2.Two) FROM TR t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t1.ID) AS Two.One,
       Three - (SELECT SUM(t2.Three) FROM TR t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t1.ID) AS Three.One
FROM TR t1
ORDER BY ID;